# Why do functions on mapped objects with computed keys not infer correct types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a need to re-map the keys of one object - as string literals - into slightly differently formatted keys for an expected object - again, as string literals.  I'm using Typescript's template string literals to do this, with version 4.9.5.  I'm also taking the value type from the first object and mapping it to the argument of a function in the second object. In my reproduction code below, I also made it the return type, just for extra clarity.  For some reason, having an inline expression for a computed key makes the type inference fail in a strange way.  Code for reproducing:

```js
type Original = { foo: 'expects a string literal', baz: boolean, bar: number }
type Mapped = {
  [prop in keyof Original as `$(${prop & string})`]: (arg: Original[prop]) => Original[prop]
}

type PropSelector<name extends string> = `$(${name & string})`
const propSelector =  <propName extends string>(propName: propName): PropSelector<propName> => `$(${propName})`

const barKey = propSelector('bar');

const workingTestObject: Mapped = {
  '$(foo)': (arg) => 'expects a string literal',
  '$(baz)': (arg) => true,
  // works just fine as a const (and not inlined)
  [barKey]: (arg) => 51345
}

const correctFailures: Mapped = {
  // Errors correctly for incorrect return types as well
  // Type 'number' not assignable to 'expects a string literal'
  '$(foo)': (arg) => 5552,
  // Type 'string' not assignable to 'boolean'
  '$(baz)': (arg) => '1234',
  // Type 'boolean' not assignable to type 'number'
  [barKey]: (arg) => true
}
```

Notice above that the `barKey` const is the result of the function call to `propSelector`, which outputs `'$(bar)'`, which is also the literal return type.  Using the const as a key in the object works exactly as it should.

However, if I simply move the `propSelector` function call inline, instead of using a separate const, it all falls apart and TS defaults the argument to `any`, although it is still able to infer the return type just fine for some reason.

```js
const failingTestObject: Mapped = {
  '$(foo)': (arg) => 'expects a string literal',
  '$(baz)': (arg) => true,
  // type check error: `arg` is implicitly `any`?  But return type is fine?
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg) => 13451
}

// return type errors correctly when using propSelector
// but cannot infer the type for arg, so gives "implicit any" error for all of them
const correctFailures: Mapped = {
  // return type expected string literal, but got number
  [propSelector('foo')]: (arg) => 5552,
  // return type expected boolean, but got string
  [propSelector('baz')]: (arg) => '1234',
  // return type expected number, but got boolean
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg) => true
}
```

Here's a playground link of the above code: https://tsplay.dev/WG2Yom

Notice that I'm being very explicit as to the literal type that is returned from the `propSelector` function which creates the key.  So, the correct inference occurs when the object key is a string, or a reference to an expression as a const (like with `barKey`), but not if the same expression is simply inlined.

I've tried a few things, like different combinations of the `& string` bit in the literal types, either one or the other, or both, or neither, with no difference in behaviour.

Does anyone know why this is?  Is it expected behaviour?  I know I can simply specify the argument type for the function inline, but I'm trying to automate as much type acquisition as possible, to avoid duplicate typing, so I'd love to make this work.  Having the expression inlined is also important in my case, so just using a const isn't great either.

Many thanks!

---

**Edit: So it turns out there was already a PR to fix this issue**, and only days after posting this, it was merged!  The PR can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51915

Comment: I'd think this is a limitation of the type inference algorithm. Type argument inference and contextual inference of function params don't always play nicely together; it's obvious to *us* the order of inference that works here (first infer the type arg for `propSelector()` and then the callback parameter type from that) but the compiler does it in whatever order it chooses and sometimes this fails to work.  Similar issues arise elsewhere as shown in [ms/TS#44999](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44999), but I didn't find an exact match.

Comment: Does that fully address the question well enough or are you looking for an authoritative answer for the particular scenario here (as opposed to the general scenario)?  If you need something more targeted then I think maybe someone would need to open a GitHub issue about it (or find one that I haven't found yet).  Let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: Very curious. I dived into the issue and created a simpler repro with more test cases: https://tsplay.dev/wgDByN It all seems to be going wrong at the argument inference + computed property name. Definitely a bug worth filing.

Comment: I really appreciate that, yeah this is what I was expecting was happening (incorrect ordering).  I'm used to Hindley-Milner type systems (I'm spoiled a bit) and there are a fair few cases in TS where that intuition I learned from Haskell and PureScript doesn't translate across.  I just wanted to be sure of myself before opening a GH issue, but looks like that's probably the way forward :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I pushed [my link in the comments](https://tsplay.dev/wgDByN) a bit further, and it seems you can effectively resolve this by giving hints to the compiler which will be type checked. As long as you setup your tsconfig to flag `any` types, you will have type-safe code:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYIHYEMA2UC8UDeUARunAFxSoCuAtkRHFAL4CwAUO6JFALLpiQAJgGFcBdlCgBtMHAD2YKGigBrCCDkAzWIhQZs6AM5QABgBIAFGfyyFTAJQmAuhQukkFeMjRYZ8sE72uAB8Ot76fgpO7KwcbADGcqiGwFC2YADKEJgQ8cByjHhQADzpAHLoNNAQAB7AEKiCximIqEjBFuWVEBRdVUE4oeZWNv4VVQ4mUEZQicnA7IsJSSmzAIwUfAIQImL4EtLpWTl5BRYA5CRw5-YuUG5wSAOhAKwANFAA9J+zBXC5qSohnQSAgHxM7imqDkqTQmgY-0EADooAAlCDAKhwVBQLjQeIAC1yakEUAAZGkjIYdkiYks5qt4gAmTb8ISiPD7NiSSKZbIAs6XUg3O4PJ4hKAAIgAktMaNMoC00EhJR9vkpUIk4P88lAgSCwdNHpQYRr4dqaWiMVicXjZkT4iTyVBNOgEDlkXS4uqMgS5FRMKT6FAIABHKgIABuWAaqXy62IVFS0OAKMAfBuAFF3M9msxn2AzUvEAMys7a7TkHKSSyxXeyS0XuZ5Qd5fH5anWA4Gg8GQs0Iy3ozHY3HgfEOp0UsBUmle9jqgAyGPOxiJmEUwCJI+4hOJDHpK0LABZS+y9pWjvzTnALlcRa53BRqHQGE2W+rhH8AXqu4asNgkHIciCAAhLOyzzLMLwnjsHLiNyhz+McArXkK1y3PejwUEqbSvmqPzSpqn66vq3bTDiCIFEoxiaJgIKgiBXpAA)

```
type Original = { bar: number }

type MappedC = {
  [prop in keyof Original as `$(${prop})`]: (arg: Original[prop]) => Original[prop]
}

const propSelector =  <propName extends string>(propName: propName) => `$(${propName})` as const


const c1: MappedC = {
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg) => 5, // correct usage, `arg` not inferred. Return type checked & passed.
}

const c2: MappedC = {
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg) => "I am a string", // incorrect usage, arg not inferred. Return type checked & failed.
}

// Should be equivalent to c1 but not. 
const c3: MappedC = {
  ["$(bar)"]: (arg) => 5, // correct usage, `arg` inferred. Return type checked & passed.
}

// Let's help the type checker

const c4: MappedC = {
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg: number) => 5, // Correct usage, all good!
}

const c5: MappedC = {
  [propSelector('bar')]: (arg: string) => 5, // Incorrect usage, an error is flagged!
}
```

In the meantime, I recommend you file an issue against the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this.  Yeah in my question I mentioned about how I could give the type hints for `arg`, but my objective was to be able to have TS infer it so one wouldn't need to write duplicate types (don't ask me why, for aesthetic reasons perhaps?).  For the time being I think you're right though, doing this is currently unavoidable.